# Is there an infinite field F with char(F)=p and not algebraically closed field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is there an infinite field F with characteristic of the  field $F$ is $p$ (p is prime) and not algebraically closed field ?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$.

Comment: If $\Omega_p$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$, any infinite proper subfield of $\Omega_p$ satisfies this condition. For example, we can consider $$K= \{ \alpha \in \Omega_p | [\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha ): \Bbb{F}_p] \mbox{ is a power of }2 \}$$

Comment: FYI, the characteristic is always prime if it is non-zero (so the clarification you give is unnecessary)

Comment: The field defined by Crostul is known as the *quadratic closure* of $\mathbb F_p$. → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field#Quadratic_closure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_p (t)$ is an example. It is defined as

$$
\mathbb{F}_p(t) = \{\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}: f(t),g(t)\ne 0 \in\mathbb{F}_p[t] \}
$$

This is the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. It is obvious that  $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$ is infinite. However, it has characteristic $p$. This is because it contains subfield $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $char(\mathbb{F}_p) = p$. Also, if we consider $X^2 - t$, we see that it is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Why $X^2-t$ does not have roots in $\mathbb{F}_p (t)$?

Comment: @MeMe, try $X=f/g$ and compare the parity of the degrees in $f^2=tg^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ is a perfect example of such a field.

If you look for an algebraic extension over $\Bbb{F}_p$, I suggest you to consider the following:
if $\Omega_p$ denotes the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$, any infinite proper subfield of $\Omega_p$ satisfies this condition. For example, we can consider $$K= \{ \alpha \in \Omega_p | [\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha ): \Bbb{F}_p] \mbox{ is a power of }2 \}$$